# How to use an older version of an application?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, updates, system

I was using an application. Then the multiplayer mode stopped working, so I decided to reinstall it. After I uninstalled the app, I realised that an update had been made and my Android version is too old to use the new version of the application.

Is there anything I can do to be able to use the application again (except for buying a phone with a newer version of android)?

I checked, there are no updates of the system for my phone.

I downloaded the appplication via Google Play Store.

Comment: You could try finding an older version that's compatible with your Android version. E.g. ask the dev to provide it (then side-load it). Also see our [alternative-markets tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/alternative-markets/info) for other sources.

Comment: How can I ask my device to provide an older version of the application?

Comment: You can't ask your *device* for that. You can ask the app's developer, he might have kept copies or at least links to them.

Comment: There's a possibility that using the older version won't make multiplayer work again *if the developer add version checking on their code*. So, you can still try to do that, but don't have too much hope.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the app's developer has changed the minimum API level for that particular app. So the *latest* version won't work on your version of Android.

You can [side-load the APK file](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2452614/how-to-sideload-an-app-onto-your-android-phone-or-tablet.html) of an earlier version onto your device to get it working again.

You may request the app's developer for an older APK or you can download from other sites that provide APKs. [APKMirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/) is a trusted repository, for example.