# how to force an old app to be supported in the higher android version than it's supposed to be?

Tags: applications, samsung, android-11, android-12

I have a very almost similar question to this discussion: [Is it possible to run old apps on newer versions of Android? If so, how?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/230952/is-it-possible-to-run-old-apps-on-newer-versions-of-android-if-so-how), the question in the discussion hasn't even got answered officially yet, so I don't think it's duplicated.

Besides my question more want to ask about the possibility if the app that used to work in my previous android version i.e Android 11 and after updating my phone to 12, the app that used to work, doesn't work anymore.

The app that I'm talking about is "Stack Exchange" i.e. the android app version of this very site and has loads of similar features to this site. Sadly, however, the app doesn't seem to have the older or the latest version and it's even rare and not listed in Play store, mind you the app used to be in Play Store, but I don't know why they removed it, the app itself doesn't seem to be dangerous and it helped me a lot to even ask, answer, pose questions and getting notifications. This is the link of the app if it matters: [Stack Exchange](https://apkcombo.com/stack-exchange/com.stackexchange.marvin/).

I'm not a developer, so if you explain rather complicated things I'm afraid I wouldn't understand. However if it's just a small edit using apktool, apkeditor I would probably understand.

Is it possible to make this app functions again as usual using small tricks? Or at least tell me why this is happening. I mean, I have another old app that worked in my previous android version (11), but is still also working now. Why only this app that doesn't work? What's the issue?

I also have collected all possible duplicates that after I read they apparently are not relevant.

I honestly think there's still hope to use this app after reading Robert's comment in this discussion: [How to use an old version of an app that wants to get updated](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233147/how-to-use-an-old-version-of-an-app-that-wants-to-get-updated). Also: [How to use an older version of an application?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/135084/how-to-use-an-older-version-of-an-application)

Comment: I know the app. The official explanation was that the mobile website works well so that no app is needed anymore (IMHO the app is way faster and reliable for daily use). Unfortunately I have bad news for you, if an app doesn't work on a newer Android version this is usually caused by new restrictions introduced by Android. To adapt an app to the new version often a lot of code changes are necessary, some times you have to rewrite parts of the app. As the Stackexchange app is closed source making those modifications is extremely hard as you have to make it on Smali code (not Java).

Comment: I'm disappointed they stopped developing the app. But anyway thanks for letting me know that.

Comment: I was an Android developer, and I know [why the Stack Exchange app doesn't work on Android 12](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372865/241919). Unfortunately, I'm not sure if I have the knowledge to reverse engineer the app and fix it. As for why it disappeared: [Why did the Stack Exchange Android app disappear from Google Play Store?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353133/241919)